# dbhydroR How to Download Information for Multiple Variables, All Stations, All Years

Tags: r

I am trying to download data sets for multiple variables for all active and inactive groundwater wells and groundwater quality in the South Florida Water Management District for all years on record using the dbhydroR package in R Studio. Some variables are from the hydrological and physical data for groundwater, and some variables are from the water quality data for groundwater.

What code can be used to bulk download this information?

Comment: If you pursue this, I would recommend splitting your query up into small enough chunks for limited manual checking. Start small with something like 5 sites and 1 variable to get an idea of the data munging issues you will need to deal with. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the advice @jsta. I think I may be better off downloading everything by county and data type from the dbhydro database on the website. There is no particular area of interest, but more recent years are of greater interest. However, as far as I can tell there seems to be no efficient way to search temporally for these variables across the entire SFWMD. Do you think it is better to download this from the database on the website or through R?

Comment: I agree that theres not a lot of functionality for getting summary stats on the data period-of-record prior to running queries. I think the answer to your question depends on how you anticipate analyzing the data. If you have a programming-based workflow I recommend R. If you are more comfortable visually curating with a spreadsheet I recommend the website. The website may also prevent you from making too large of a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tldr;** You can do this but it is not really possible without a lot of manual intervention.

For hydro data, you *could* feed all the sites on the station map (https://www.sfwmd.gov/sites/default/files/documents/em_well_monitor_map.pdf) to `get_hydro` by feeding it a really long vector of stationids. To do this you would set the stationid argument to a really long vector instead of the two sites shown below:

```
get_hydro(stationid = c("C-54", "G-561"), 
    category = "GW", freq = "DA", 
    date_min = "1990-01-01", date_max = "1990-02-02", 
    longest = TRUE)
```

For water quality data, you *could* feed all the sites on the station map (http://my.sfwmd.gov/WAB/EnvironmentalMonitoring/index.html) along with all the `test_name`(s) on the table at http://my.sfwmd.gov/dbhydroplsql/show_dbkey_info.show_data_type_info to the `get_wq` function by expanding the vectors passed to the `test_name` and `station_id` arguments:

```
get_wq(station_id = c("FLAB08", "FLAB09"),
    date_min = "2011-03-01", date_max = "2012-05-01",
    test_name = c("CHLOROPHYLLA-SALINE", "SALINITY"))
```

In addition to the possibility that this query may break either the dbhydro servers or your local machine, there are several reasons why this **may not return the result you expect**. I'm afraid that the underlying database is much too messy write code to get all variables for a given station through time in an unsupervised way. One issue is that there is no canonical dataset for variable `X` at site `Y`. Instead the database is very messy such that the record for each variable at each site changes through time.

## Hydro data

For hydro sites, the data-record is often represented by multiple datasets that have a different id (dbkey, in the case of hydro data). These numbers can change for an unknown number of reasons; Maybe a sampling or laboratory protocol change or who knows. The time periods can overlap or have a gap. For example see the output of:

```
get_dbkey(stationid = c("C-54"), 
    category = "GW", freq = "DA")
```

> Dbkey Group Data Type Freq Recorder  Start Date    End Date
>
> 1 P0916  C-54      WELL   DA     MOD1 01-JAN-1978 31-DEC-2013
>
> 2 01952  C-54      WELL   DA     ???? 10-FEB-1951 20-DEC-2016
>
> 3 05669  C-54      WELL   DA     ???? 23-NOV-1976 11-APR-1977
>
> 4 06584  C-54      WELL   DA     ???? 31-MAR-1977 03-OCT-1978

`dbhydroR` does not have sufficient logic to select the "correct" dbkey or concatenate the results of several "correct" dbkeys. It can be roughly automated by using the `longest` argument to pick the longest period-of-record dataset for each variable x site combination (the `longest` argument is new and is not on CRAN, it's only on Github for now):

```
get_dbkey(stationid = c("C-54"), 
    category = "GW", freq = "DA", longest = TRUE)
```

> Dbkey Group Data Type Freq Recorder  Start Date    End Date
>
> 2 01952  C-54      WELL   DA     ???? 10-FEB-1951 20-DEC-2016

## Water quality data

Similar messiness issues occur in the water quality data. There are no cleaned ready-to-go (curated) records of each variable at each site. Instead, the period-of-record gets split each time a sampling or measurement protocol changes. For example, look at how chlorophyll-A is represented by three different test names. Frustratingly, there is no way to tell what the period-of-record is for this data until you attempt to pull it. You would also have decide how to deal with quality assurance flags.